# Cache Replication in Clustered Environment using EHCache JGroups

Tags: caching, ehcache, jgroups

I am using EhCache framework to cache application data and thinking to use JGroups cache replication to replicate cache in a clustered environment.

Is it really an industry standard for cache replication in clustered environment? Or, there can be other better options that I should think about. Please notice that I am not using any centralized cache server at this point of time. I have already done POC on JGroups Cache Replication. Could you please share your experience in terms of its robustness and major concerns? What are the pros cons of using JGroups for cache replication?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jgroups for clustering various application nodes. We have our own cache implementation which uses the underlying Jgroups for data replication/distribution. So far it is working fine without issues.

Could you please check '[infinispan](http://infinispan.org/)'. It's a distributed cache which uses Jgroups for handling cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look on link your provided.